# Can i use SSD M.2 NVMe on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have the gaming loptop Acer Aspire VX 15 and would like to upgrade my SSD capacity. Currently i have an M.2 SATA III (Kingston 128gb Solid State Drive Rbu-sns8180ds3/128gh SSD).

My question is, can i upgrade with a M.2 NVMe? I guess it will depend on my laptop if it supports PCIe right?

Thanks!

Comment: The drive needs a PCI-e interface to plug into. I have that on my laptop here.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, can I upgrade with an M.2 NVMe?

It appears that the `Acer Aspire VX 15` does indeed have 1 M.2 SATA port and 1 M.2 NVMe port.  If you have any doubts, the specification of your laptop should indicate if NVMe is supported or not; I, unfortunately, was unable to find your laptop model on the Acer website.

> Yes, it's compatible with M.2 SATA SSD as well in addition to M.2 NVMe SSD, not any other type is compatible.

Source: [Compatible M.2 SSD slot for Acer Aspire VX 15 (VX 5 591g)](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/547497/compatible-m-2-ssd-slot-for-acer-aspire-vx-15-vx-5-591g)

Unfortunately, I cannot confirm that you actually have a `VX 5 591g`, if you have any doubts then you should stick with an M.2 SATA drive.